# Suppress sslpeerunverifiedexception while creating socket

Tags: android, hostname, sni, sslsocketfactory

I need to set SNI to my socketFactory. So I have been using the class `SSLCertificateSocketFactory`.
While creating an socket, it gives me a `sslpeerunverifiedexception`, as there is no SAN set, to the server certificate. Can I some how suppress this exception, and ask it to allow creation of socket irrespective of the server certificate?

Following is my code :

```
            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            SSLCertificateSocketFactory ssf = (SSLCertificateSocketFactory) SSLCertificateSocketFactory
                    .getDefault(0);

            ssf.setTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { tm });

            m_sslsocket = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(m_socket, m_host, m_port, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the SSLCertificateSocketFactory with  [getInsecure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.html#getInsecure(int,%20android.net.SSLSessionCache))  worked for me. It returns a new instance of a socket factory with all SSL security checks disabled.

```
SSLCertificateSocketFactory ssf = (SSLCertificateSocketFactory) SSLCertificateSocketFactory
                    .getInsecure(0, null);
```